# jquery to find all the elements inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find all the anchor tags inside a div tag and need to append one more property to the anchor tag. say `target="_blank"`.

How can i do this in using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean all the anchors in *any* div element, or in some specific div element? If it's the former, this will do the trick:

```
$('div a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

If it's a particular div you're interested in, give that element an id attribute and then use it like so:

```
$('#divid a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

replacing "divid" with the id in question.

Can you be more specific about what exactly you want?

In any case, you're going to need to use the `attr()` function to set the attribute; see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: i have one div tag, in which i need to find all the href tags and add the attribute target="_blank". I tried this, but is not working. name of my div is "divLogo". am i missing something? My master page has the jquery script reference.

Comment: The name of your div, or the id of your div? There's a big difference. If your div has an `id` attribute of `divLogo`, then you'd use `$('#divLogo a').attr('target', '_blank')` to do this. The `#` symbol is telling the function to look for an element with an `id` of `divLogo`. The `a` separated by a space tells it to look for `a` elements that are within that element.

Comment: I suggest you read up on jQuery selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You are probably interested in a single div, not every div on page, so You have to identify it.

```
$('div#theDivsId a').attr('target','_blank');
```

or

```
$('div.theDivsClass a').attr('target','_blank');
```

PS. read [**documentation**](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#yourDIV a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Have you read the jQuery docs? This can't be more basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div a').attr('target','_blank');
```